# iOS 10.3 Gmail app synchronization issues

Tags: ios, email, data-synchronization, gmail, notifications

Since updating my iPhone 6S Plus to iOS 10.3 I stumbled on a bug that I really need some help resolving or at least confirmation that it exists.

The problem is with the Gmail app on iOS, which is set up to work with my two Gmail email accounts.

Problem: Since the update, my Gmail app is not synching data and I get no notifications that I have received an email. I have a badge stuck on the app of 1 unread email even though when I actually go into the app, I have 10-15 unread emails, for which I did not receive a single notification.

In the settings, Gmail is allowed background refresh, all notifications and access is allowed to Gmail. I do not use the default Mail app, which is why I have turned email sync off and just left the calendar sync on. I have tried removing the app several times and reinstalling it to no avail.

Does anyone else experience this issue? Has anyone found a way to fix it? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to re-enter a password into your Google account setup on your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my phone and set it up as a new phone. The issue is fixed and it seems like and app was blocking the google synchronization.

My suspicion is that it is purevpn and its profile that could be getting in the way.